# change gap between bars in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped bars plot in R, ggplot2. There are two groups A and B (variable Stimulation). for each group there are two bars (pre and end) for a total of 4 bars. I am able to modify the gap between pre and end BUT not between the grouped bars A  and B ( too distant). Could you help me?
Thank you in advance
This is my code.

```
cols <- c( "#660000", "#000333")

TPS <- ggplot(Tonic_pupilsize, aes(x=Stimulation, y= (Tonic), fill = factor(Time))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean, show.legend = T, width=0.4,  position = position_dodge(width=0.45)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "#D55E00", "#0072B2"), name = "", labels = c("Pre", "End")) 
TPS

TPS1 <- TPS + stat_summary(fun.data =mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width=0.4, size=0.6, position = position_dodge(width=0.45))

TPS2 <- TPS1 +  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Time)),
                           size = 4, alpha = 0.3, 
                           position = position_dodge(width = 0.45))+
                        guides(color = FALSE) +
                    scale_colour_manual(values = cols)

TPS3 <- TPS2 + labs(x = "",  y = "  (px)") + # change labels
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A", "B"), expand = c(0, 0.2)) + theme_bw() +   #change background
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=26, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 22),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=22, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 22, face="bold"),  # change labels
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + #change backgroujd
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2600), expand = c(0, 0)) 

TPS3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide minimal and reproducible example of your data. Make the data as small as you can to and then use `dput()`. If you use any package include the library calls, e.g. `library(ggplot2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It very depends on your data, but e.g. if you use [`position_dodge2()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) instead of `position_dodge()`, you are able to define the `padding` between the grouped bars (default is 0.1).

So e.g.:

```
position = position_dodge2(width = 0.45, padding = 0)
```

inside you code.